# Could not load file or assembly'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#

Hi every1 I need help I get this error when I run my application

"Could not load file or assembly 'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. "

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Stack Trace:

[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +210
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +242
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +17
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +122

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +12857578
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +503
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +142
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +334
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +148
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +172
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1151

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12979668
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12819261

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer its as follows
 You go into your IIS 7 manager console, find the application pool your app is running in, right-click on it, go to Advanced Settings, and change the Enable 32-bit Applications setting to true:

Answer (score 0):

Bad Image Format Exception usually means you tried to load a x64 Assembly / native DLL into an 32Bit process or vice versa a 32Bit Assembly into an x64 Process.

First check in Task Manager if your application runs in 32 Bit or in your project settings under build if you compile against a specific instruction set (x86 or x64) or if you have "prefer 32 Bit" checked on that same property page of your project. Then determine which type your assembly 'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' is (using reflector). Both should be any cpu or the same type x86 or x64. If there is no difference, it could still be some natice library or a dependency of that assembly that causes the trouble. Therefor check the references of 'ActiproSoftware.Shared.Net20' with reflector and if you have all of them in the correct build.

Comment: sorry maybe i'm not getting you well what do you mean by in my project settings? I right clicked on my project>properties>Build on Configuration its Active(Debug) Platform is Active(Any CPU) and the platform target is Any CPU

Comment: If you build AnyCPU and run your application on a 64Bit CPU your application will be executed in 64Bit (if a 64Bit .NET Framework is installed). If you use native C++ libraries or third party .NET assemblies these could be compiled for x86 thus resulting in a Bad Image Format exception.

I would suggest you check all your references if you load an .NET assembly or a native library that is compiled for x86/32Bit.

Build your application once for 64Bit and once for 32Bit. One of them should run without problems. The other one shows you which type of external non working reference you got.